# Rails admin and cancancan, undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I've followed the guides in the cancancan wiki on how to use cancancan to authenticate admins for rails_admin. It works so far, but when I try to access the admin dashboard with an account that has admin privileges, I run into the error

> NoMethodError in RailsAdmin::MainController#dashboard
>
> undefined method 'new' for nil:NilClass

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LorX1.jpg

What's going on and how can I fix this?

---

ability.rb

```
 if user.admin?
    can :manage, :all
    can :access, :rails_admin # this line
    can :dashboard, :all # and this one
  elsif user.userrole?
    can :read, Item
    can :manage, User, :user_id=>user.id
  else
    can :read, Item
  end
```

---

rails_admin.rb

```
config.authorize_with :cancancan2
```

According to [the rails_admin wiki](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/CanCanCan)

---

Specifics:

rails 5.1.5

cancancan 2.1.3

rails_admin 1.3.0

devise 4.4.3

Answer (score 2):

rails_admin.rb

```
  ### Popular gems integration

  ## == Devise ==
  config.authenticate_with do
    warden.authenticate! scope: :user
  end
  config.current_user_method(&:current_user)

  ## == CancanCan ==
  ## 「cancan」 ng
  ## 「cancancan」 ok
  config.authorize_with :cancancan
```

Answer (score 1):

I could solve it by reinstalling the admin_rails gem, In the terminal

> $ rails g rails_admin:install

then I gave him overwrite YES

Answer (score 0):

I tried to fix it but could not, so I went for Pundit gem and It worked fine with rails admin, They also have a gem with rails admin implementation which you can use. Kudos

Comment: Would you elaborate on what this fixes? Perhaps add a link to this gem?

Comment: `https://github.com/sudosu/rails_admin_pundit`
Here is the link to the gem which is totally configurable with rails admin. Difference was In **CanCan**, we define the ability class, but in pundit, we define **policies** for each model and change the configuration of rails admin as 
`config.authorize_with :pundit`

Comment: The link is [https://github.com/sudosu/rails_admin_pundit](https://github.com/sudosu/rails_admin_pundit),  actually I was having 2,3 different issues with `CANCAN` and `Rails Admin`, I tried to fix them, did some R&D and found nothing. So I switched to Pundit, I suggest in your case if you do not find any help you should also switch to Pundit. :)

Comment: Hey Jeff, did you fix the problem with CanCan? If so then can you please share the fix :)

Comment: I wasn’t working on this myself; I added a comment while moderating this to encourage you to add the link to that gem, which you already did. Sadly, I don’t have anything else to offer for this. Sorry!

Comment: I worked around and found nothing for `CanCan`, `rails_admin_pundit` has some limitations but works like a charm.